# Bounded Linear Operator from $L^p[0,1]$ to itself

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

In the normed space $L^p[0,1] (1\leq p \leq \infty)$, linear operator V is defined as $(Vf)(x)  = \int^x_0 f(t)dt , f\in L^p[0,1], x \in [0,1]$.

Then, show that $V$ is bounded linear operator from $L^p[0,1]$ to $L^p[0,1]$.

Indeed, $V$ is linear operator, since $V(af+bg)(x) = \int^x_0 (af+bg)(t)dt$.
But, I am having some trouble showing "Bounded".

$\Vert V\Vert = sup \{\Vert Vf \Vert_p : \Vert f \Vert _p \leq 1,\ f \in L^p[0,1]\}$

How can I get $\Vert Vf \Vert_p$ is bounded from given conditions? Multiple integral and "^p" make this solution harder and harder. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Rewrite your integral as $\int_{[0,1]} f(t) \chi_{[0,x]}(t)\,dt$ and use Holder's inequality.

Comment: You get a pretty straightforward norm inequality from it that is an equivalent definition of boundedness for operators *a la* $T$ is bounded iff $\|Tf\| \le C\|f\|$ for some $C\ge 0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval $|Vf(x)| \leq \|f|\|_p$ for all $x$ which implies that $\|Vf\|_p \leq \|f\|_p$.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks! I got the first inequality but did not realize it implied the second one.